# Drupal fields: Programmatically insert select list options

Tags: php, input, drupal-7, field

I have a List(Text) field within which I providing a list of dates starting with the current date. These dates provide dropdown selectable options to the users.

I need to provide the "list of dates" programmatically so that whatever day it is, the system will automatically print the current current date as the first date.

The problem is the **allowed values list** does not support a PHP format.

How might I accomplish my task as outlined above?

Answer (score 0):

Try Drupal Date module, if that does not have option then what you can do is create the 
form from the UI without 'select date element' that you want to do programatically.

After that get the 'id' of the form by debugging the 'html source' of the form_id . Afterwards use `hook_form_alter(&$form, & $form_state, $form_id)`

```
function my_form_alter(&$form, & $form_state, $form_id)  { 
 if ($form_id == 'MY_FORM_ID' ) { 

   $date_key_format =  "m/d/y";  ; 
   $date_value_format = "F j, Y, g:i a"; 
   $options = array(date($date_key_format) => date($date_value_format)); 

   for ($i = 1; $i < 10; $i++ ) { 
     $options[date($date_key_format, strtotime("+$i days"))] = date($date_value_format, strtotime("+$i days")) 
   } 

   $form['date'] = array (
     '#type' => 'select' , 
     '#title' => 'Select Date' , 
     '#options' => $options
     '#weight' => 5 //based on where you want this element position to be 


   ); 

 } 

}
```

In the above select options , it will start from the current date and continues upto to 10th say from current date.